# Need to improve speed of processing

Tags: c#, postgresql, ado.net, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

"I have a script of insert and update in a folder which is executed by window service. In the window service, there is a function that will check and get the batch of 10 files and executes and move to the success or failure folder. Now the script volume is increased and the window service is taking a long time to process the scripts."

```
public bool CheckQueueExist()
{
    bool commitstatus = false;
    string fullfilepath = string.Empty;
    StringBuilder strQueryBuild = new StringBuilder();
    try
    {
        if (QueueVariables.NewFolderPath == "")
        {
            LoadFilePath();
        }

        string path = QueueVariables.NewFolderPath;
        DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        FileInfo[] files = info.GetFiles().OrderBy(p => p.CreationTime).ThenBy(a => a.Name).Take(10).ToArray();
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            fullfilepath = file.FullName;
            string Filename = file.Name;
            try
            {
                string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file.FullName);
                string query = "";
                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    query = query + line;
                }
                strQueryBuild.Append(query);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                commitstatus = false;
                AppHelper.ErrrorLog(ex, "File in USE: " + fullfilepath);
            }
        }
        int RowsAffected = 0;

        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strQueryBuild.ToString()))
            {
                string connstr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xyz"].ConnectionString;
                using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstr))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    var tra = conn.BeginTransaction();
                    try
                    {
                        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                        cmd.CommandText = strQueryBuild.ToString();
                        RowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        if (RowsAffected == 0)
                        {
                            RowsAffected = 1;
                            // Even Condition not Match, the Query has accepted.So it should be consider as 1
                        }
                        tra.Commit();
                        commitstatus = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        commitstatus = false;
                        AppHelper.ErrrorLog(ex, "UploadFileData-Error1");
                        RowsAffected = -1;
                        tra.Rollback();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            commitstatus = false;
            AppHelper.ErrrorLog(ex, "ProcessQueue-Error2");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want run with bulk insert?which line do you have slow?can you show example query?

Comment: Why are you using ```ReadAllLines``` and concatenating in a loop to build a single overall string with a ```StringBuilder```? Surely just use ```ReadAllText``` to get a single string equivalent to what you build with ```strQueryBuild``` and ditch all the memory intensive string operations? Also, since the content of your builder is your SQL query, it would seem rather large and possibly slow. Are there optimizations you could make to use a stored procedure instead?

Comment: That Service... is it called "EasyAttacVector.exe" by any chance?

Comment: @abolfazlsadeghi Yes I want to run the bulk query and ExecuteNonQuery taking time to execute.

Comment: @majixin Thanks for the suggestion, I will try to implement with ReadAlltext. Another thing I would like to ask, I've used Parallel.ForEach in which I have to open and close connection every time for 10 times for each 10 files, which leads to network overhead so is there any possible solution for that ?

Comment: @Fildor comment of "EasyAttacVector" is highlighting your SQL Injection attack risk by running text read from a file as your SQL query. If somebody can alter the content of one of your queries suitably, they can gain access to the database pretty easily. You need to protect against this, even if your application is only used internally. In terms of re-using your SQL connection, you can setup a connection pool to lower the overhead involved: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling

Comment: @Fildor No......

Comment: Sorry about the ironic comment. I took it somewhat for common sense to consider this highly dangerous. I figure now, that was kind of arrogant of me. Honest apologies. Yes, my intention was to point out the danger of being injected with and executing malicious code.